# How to modify this query to use between startindex and endindex rownum

Tags: database, oracle, between, row-number, rownum

How to modify this query so that I get the results between rownum 10 and 21 for example:

```
   SELECT DAL_ROWNOTABLE.DAL_ID
     FROM (SELECT ticket.id AS "DAL_ID" 
          FROM ticket_table ticket 
          WHERE (ticket.type = N'I' ) AND 
        (ticket.tenant IS NULL OR
         ticket.tenant IN (SELECT tgm.tenant_id 
                           FROM tenant_group_member tgm
                           WHERE tgm.tenant_group = HEXTORAW('30B0716FEB5F4E4BB82A7B7AA3A1A42C') 
                          ) 
        )
  ORDER BY ticket.id
 ) DAL_ROWNOTABLE 
  WHERE rownum <= 21;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `rownum` to `row_number()`:

```
SELECT DAL_ROWNOTABLE.DAL_ID
FROM (SELECT ticket.id AS "DAL_ID",row_number() over (order by ticket_id) as seqnum
      FROM ticket_table ticket 
      WHERE (ticket.type = N'I' )AND
            (ticket.tenant IS NULL OR
            ticket.tenant IN(SELECT tgm.tenant_id 
                              FROM tenant_group_member tgm
                              WHERE tgm.tenant_group = HEXTORAW('30B0716FEB5F4E4BB82A7B7AA3A1A42C') 
                             ) 
        )
     ) DAL_ROWNOTABLE 
WHERE seqnum between 10 and 21;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I suggested using ROW_NUMBER() in my answer to this guy's other question.

Comment: @APC . . . I remember, and that was a fine solution.  I used `rownum` just as part of simplifying the query.

Comment: hahaha Gordon again ...Thanks man will try this out...I thought of using MINUS

Comment: I will have to check why the code uses ROWNUM own implementation instead of using ROW_NUMBER which seems to be straightforward according to you...